# Is there such a thing as "light leveling"?

Tags: visible-light

I was looking at my fireplace and wondering if you could use a flickering light source like a candle or fireplace fire and turn it into a constant light source so that it doesn't flicker anymore. How could that be achieved?

Example could be, you are in front of a fireplace and want to read the newspaper. You can't because the light is flickering to such a degree your eyes start huting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to filter time fluctuations  away from some 
kinds of illumination.   The key, is to use indirect light,
generated from phosphors that are pumped from a (ultraviolet or blue)
short-wavelength light source, that have a slow release of longer
wavelength light.   Some such phosphors (strontium aluminate)
are quite bright for many minutes after receiving input illumination.

This is the principle of all the glow-in-the-dark items you've
ever seen.   Those, don't flicker!

This is,  however, unlikely to work well with reddish firelight,
which can only excite deep-red or infrared phosphors.

It is really a conversion of light to electron excitation, followed
by a secondary light emission as the excited electron returns to the
low-energy state in which it is stable.   So, the output light is
new, not the original source light.   One could also, of course,
charge a solar-powered flashlight to accomplish something similar.

Actually delaying light is theoretically possible (in a laboratory)
by use of some kinds of nonlinear materials, but that isn't
a practical illumination option.

Comment: Interesting answer. Thank you very much. I didn't think about light as a power source for "new" lights. But that makes sense.